# Summation notation of X^2

Tags: summation

Is this correct? If so a link to more information/proof would be appreciated. Thanks!

$$\sum_{k=1}^x(k + k - 1) = x^2$$

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5Bk+%2B+k+-+1,+%7Bk,+1,+x%7D%5D+%3D+x%5E2)

Comment: Remember what Sum_{k=1}^x k is. Use it and calculate, Mathematica not needed here.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks mgamer for bringing it down to basics. x^2/2 + x/2 + x^2/2 + x/2 -x = x^2

Answer (score 1):

You can do this one by induction.

The base case is that $\sum_{k=1}^1(2k - 1) = 1^2$ and this is pretty much self evident. Supposing it holds for the first $n$ positive integers means that:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(2k - 1) =  \sum_{k=1}^{n}(2k - 1) +2(n+1)-1=n^2+2n+1=(n+1)^2$$

Hence it holds for all positive integers.